# TSQL Cascade / Waterfall value from current row into the next

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, common-table-expression

My earlier edits were a little muddled. Hopefully this clears it up ...

TL/DR -- just copy and execute the two script blocks and it will become apparent.

---

I have a question on cascading data. Essentially I am trying to move data down in a waterfall effect according to some predefined conditions (below). I've solved 15 of the 18 scenarios and I help with the remaining 3, scenario's with GID's 9, 10 and 18.

For a bit of perspective, in the system I'm working on data is continually imported into the system.  The data is sparse, and I'm working to reconstitute a full set of data to complete the import process.  I have little control over the shape of the data in the system, or that is provided to me:-/

*Ultimately the question is: how do I satisfy the 5 cascading rules below, or alternately, how do I solve for test case #18 I've provided in the script below?*

**The Cascade Rules**
In this simplified scenario the 'rules' for cascading are as follows:

- Data will be cascaded only within the same group (`GID`)
- A group of data will be ordered starting at 1 (`Seq`)
- `IsLive` column will be either 1 or 0
- If `IsLive = 1` then move data down the rows until you encounter another `IsLive = 1` or `IsLive = 0` which has a non-null value
- If `IsLive = 0` then move data down the rows until you hit another `IsLive = 0` with a value.

*Note:  My script is a simplified example, but in the full scenario there are `N` columns on which I need to cascade.*

**Solution Notes**
If you run the SQL below you will see 3 columns, Input, Output - result of the CTE, Expected - the expected result and Result - Pass/Fail.  I have included a script that **both** creates sample tables and illustrates test cases simply by executing.

- The test cases script below has sample data
- The test case script has a column I appended for the *correct expected value*. (Look for GID=18 in the INSERT script.)

I hope someone can help, if not I might have to resort to a SQL CLR SP solution. Also, I'm not tied to this solution, you may also completely discard my solution and come up with something new.

**Test Case**

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (GID int, Seq int, IsLive bit, 
                     Eff date, 
                     Name varchar(50), 
                     Expected varchar(50)) -- expected val should help debug!

INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1, 1, 1, '01-08-2012', 'RTS', 'RTS')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1, 2, 0, '01-09-2012', 'RTA', 'RTA')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1, 3, 1, '01-10-2012', 'FSA', 'RTA')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1, 4, 0, '01-11-2012',  NULL, 'RTA')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (1, 5, 1, '01-12-2012', 'FSA', 'RTA')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2, 1, 1, '01-08-2012', 'RTS', 'RTS')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2, 2, 0, '01-09-2012', 'RTA', 'RTA')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2, 3, 1, '01-10-2012', 'FSA', 'RTA')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2, 4, 0, '01-11-2012', 'GSM', 'GSM')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2, 5, 1, '01-12-2012', 'FSA', 'GSM')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (3, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', 'FSA', 'FSA')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (3, 2, 0, '01-02-2012', NULL, 'FSA')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (4, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (4, 2, 0, '01-02-2012', 'FSA', 'FSA')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (4, 3, 0, '01-03-2012', NULL, 'FSA')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (5, 1, 0, '01-01-2012', NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (5, 2, 1, '01-02-2012', 'LSI', 'LSI')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (5, 3, 0, '01-03-2012', NULL, 'LSI')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (6, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (6, 2, 0, '01-02-2012', 'LSI', 'LSI')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (6, 3, 1, '01-03-2012', NULL, 'LSI')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (7, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', 'FSA', 'FSA')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (7, 2, 0, '01-02-2012', NULL, 'FSA')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (7, 3, 1, '01-03-2012', 'RTA', 'RTA')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (8, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', 'FSA', 'FSA')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (8, 2, 0, '01-02-2012', NULL, 'FSA')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (8, 3, 1, '01-03-2012', NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (9, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', 'FSA', 'FSA')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (9, 2, 1, '01-02-2012', NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (9, 3, 1, '01-03-2012', 'RTS', 'RTS')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (10, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', 'FSA','FSA')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (10, 2, 1, '01-02-2012', 'GSM','GSM')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (10, 3, 1, '01-03-2012', 'RTS','RTS')  
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (11, 1, 0, '01-01-2012', 'NOP','NOP')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (11, 2, 1, '01-02-2012', 'TAP','NOP')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (11, 3, 1, '01-03-2012', 'STG','NOP')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (12, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', 'RTS','RTS')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (12, 2, 0, '01-02-2012', 'RTM','RTM')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (12, 3, 1, '01-03-2012', 'LSA','RTM')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (12, 4, 1, '01-03-2012', 'LSA','RTM')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (12, 5, 1, '01-03-2012', 'GSM','RTM')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (13, 1, 1, '01-08-2012', 'BAR','BAR')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (13, 2, 0, '01-09-2012', NULL, 'BAR')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (13, 3, 1, '01-10-2012', 'TST','TST')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (14, 1, 1, '01-08-2012', 'BAR','BAR')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (14, 2, 0, '01-09-2012', 'GIP','GIP')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (14, 3, 1, '01-10-2012', 'TST','GIP')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (15, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', 'BAR','BAR')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (15, 2, 0, '01-02-2012', 'BAR','BAR')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (15, 3, 1, '01-02-2012', 'BAR','BAR')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (15, 4, 1, '01-02-2012', 'GYM','BAR')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (16, 1, 1, '01-02-2012', 'BAR','BAR')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (16, 2, 0, '01-03-2012', NULL, 'BAR')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (16, 3, 1, '01-03-2012', 'BAR','BAR')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (16, 4, 1, '01-03-2012', 'GYM','GYM')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (17, 1, 1, '01-02-2012', 'BAR', 'BAR')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (17, 2, 0, '01-03-2012', 'GIP', 'GIP')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (17, 3, 0, '01-03-2012', NULL,  'GIP') 
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (17, 4, 1, '01-03-2012', 'TST', 'GIP') 

-- -------------------------------------------
-- Following is the GID=18 test case that fails
-- -------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (18, 1, 1, '01-02-2012', 'BAR', 'BAR')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (18, 2, 0, '01-03-2012', 'BAR', 'BAR')
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (18, 3, 0, '01-03-2012', NULL, 'BAR') 
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (18, 4, 1, '01-03-2012', 'TST', 'BAR')
```

**Solution**

```
DECLARE @PrevNonLiveSeq int = NULL

;WITH CTE AS ( 
    SELECT  T.GID, T.SEQ, T.IsLive, Expected
            , Name AS Name
            , CASE WHEN T.IsLive = 0 THEN T.SEQ ELSE NULL END As PrevNonLiveSeq
            , CASE WHEN T.IsLive = 1 THEN T.SEQ ELSE NULL END As PrevLiveSeq
            , NULL AS PerNonLiveSeqCalc
            , NULL AS PerLiveSeqCalc
            , 0 PrevSeq
            , CAST(NULL AS varchar(50)) PrevName
    FROM    @Test T
    WHERE   T.Seq = 1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT  Curr.GID, Curr.SEQ, Curr.IsLive, Curr.Expected
            ,CASE   WHEN Curr.IsLive = 0 THEN ISNULL(Curr.Name, Prev.Name) 
                    ELSE CASE   WHEN PrevNonLive.Name IS NULL THEN 
                                    CASE WHEN Prev.Name <> PrevLive.Name THEN Prev.Name ELSE Curr.Name END
                                ELSE Prev.Name END
             END

            ,CASE WHEN Curr.IsLive = 0 THEN Curr.SEQ ELSE Prev.PrevNonLiveSeq END As PrevNonLiveSeq
            ,CASE WHEN Curr.IsLive = 1 THEN Curr.SEQ ELSE Prev.PrevLiveSeq END As PrevLiveSeq
            , ISNULL(Prev.PrevNonLiveSeq, Curr.SEQ) AS PerNonLiveSeqCalc
            , ISNULL(Prev.PrevLiveSeq, Curr.SEQ) AS PerLiveSeqCalc
            , Prev.Seq PrevSeq, Prev.Name PrevName
    FROM    CTE Prev 
    JOIN    @Test Curr ON Curr.GID = Prev.GID AND Curr.SEQ = Prev.SEQ+1
    JOIN    @Test PrevNonLive ON Prev.GID = PrevNonLive.GID AND PrevNonLive.SEQ = ISNULL(Prev.PrevNonLiveSeq, Curr.SEQ)
    JOIN    @Test PrevLive ON Prev.GID = PrevLive.GID AND PrevLive.SEQ = ISNULL(Prev.PrevLiveSeq, Curr.SEQ)
) 
SELECT CTE.GID, CTE.Seq, T.IsLive
        , T.Name Input, CTE.Name [Output]
        , CASE WHEN CTE.Name = CTE.Expected OR (CTE.Name IS NULL AND CTE.Expected IS NULL) THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'FAIL' END AS Result
        , CTE.Expected
FROM CTE 
INNER JOIN @Test T on CTE.GID = T.GID AND CTE.Seq = T.Seq
ORDER BY CTE.GID, CTE.Seq
```

### **Results**

For results please copy and run in SSMS

Thanks!

Comment: I admit I haven't run your code, but it isn't immediately obvious what your actual question is: you mention "having trouble" but you haven't said what that means or which "test case" you're referring to.

Comment: @Pondlife added failed test case number.

Comment: Can you clarify ..is test case 18 the series of inserts starting with 'VALUES (18,' ?  How should it look vs how does it look?

Comment: Edited to provide calrity to the question

Comment: I might be missing something, but I am trying to match up your rules to the expected results and I am not seeing how groups 9 and 10 equate to the If IsLive = 1 rule. Also, maybe put parens around the appropriate parts of the If IsLive = 1 rule to remove ambiguity around what "non-NULL value" applies to; and you might have an extraneous "5" at the end of the If IsLive = 0 rule.

Comment: @stritzky -- the 5 was my doing when editing the OP to try to frame his question.  Fixed.

Comment: @srutzky Fixed the test case. Thanks!

Comment: @KShan: I see some updates, thanks. Are groups 9 and 10 supposed to fail now? Seems to imply that either the rule is wrong/incomplete or you have more than group 18 to fix ;-). And still would help to get the parens in the IsLive = 1 rule :).

Comment: @srutzky Yes 9 and 10 also fail currently, it seems I have more than just group 18 to fix. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: @GilM you answered a previous similar question of mine, do you want to take a swing at this one?

Answer (score 1):

This should work and does not require the recursive CTE.  You would just need to do the COALESCE for each of the actual fields you wanted to "cascade".

```
SELECT crrnt.*, COALESCE(cscd.Name, crrnt.Name) AS [Output]
FROM @Test crrnt
OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT  TOP 1 *
            FROM    @Test prir
            WHERE   prir.GID = crrnt.GID
            AND     prir.Seq < crrnt.Seq
            AND     (
                        (
                            crrnt.IsLive = 1
                        AND prir.IsLive = 0
                        AND prir.Name IS NOT NULL
                        )
                    OR  (
                            crrnt.IsLive = 0 
                        AND crrnt.Name IS NULL
                        AND (
                                (
                                    prir.IsLive = 0
                                AND prir.Name IS NOT NULL
                                )
                            OR  (
                                    prir.IsLive = 1
                                AND NOT EXISTS(
                                                SELECT  *
                                                FROM    @Test confirm
                                                WHERE   confirm.GID = prir.GID
                                                AND     confirm.Seq < prir.Seq
                                                AND     confirm.IsLive = 0
                                                AND     confirm.Name IS NOT NULL
                                            )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
            ORDER BY    prir.Seq DESC
            ) cscd
```

**Edit:**
It is generally a good idea to test the performance of your queries so the following is just that.  The test consists of:
 1. Start with originally posted query and sample data
 2. Change Temp Variable to Temp Table (query will end up hitting real User Table)
 3. Create Clustered Index on Temp Table, being: GID, Seq.
 4. Duplicate the data, but with higher GID values (turn 18 rows into 6,300,063 rows)
 5. Ensure equal environment with DBCC FREEPROCCACAHE and DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
 6. Use STATISTICS IO and STATISTICS TIME

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
-- DROP TABLE #Test
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Test') IS NULL)
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #Test (GID INT NOT NULL, Seq INT NOT NULL, IsLive BIT NOT NULL, 
                     Eff date, 
                     Name varchar(50), 
                     Expected varchar(50), -- expected val should help debug!
                     PRIMARY KEY(GID, Seq)
                     )

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (1, 1, 1, '01-08-2012', 'RTS', 'RTS')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (1, 2, 0, '01-09-2012', 'RTA', 'RTA')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (1, 3, 1, '01-10-2012', 'FSA', 'RTA')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (1, 4, 0, '01-11-2012',  NULL, 'RTA')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (1, 5, 1, '01-12-2012', 'FSA', 'RTA')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (2, 1, 1, '01-08-2012', 'RTS', 'RTS')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (2, 2, 0, '01-09-2012', 'RTA', 'RTA')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (2, 3, 1, '01-10-2012', 'FSA', 'RTA')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (2, 4, 0, '01-11-2012', 'GSM', 'GSM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (2, 5, 1, '01-12-2012', 'FSA', 'GSM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (3, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', 'FSA', 'FSA')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (3, 2, 0, '01-02-2012', NULL, 'FSA')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (4, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (4, 2, 0, '01-02-2012', 'FSA', 'FSA')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (4, 3, 0, '01-03-2012', NULL, 'FSA')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (5, 1, 0, '01-01-2012', NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (5, 2, 1, '01-02-2012', 'LSI', 'LSI')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (5, 3, 0, '01-03-2012', NULL, 'LSI')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (6, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (6, 2, 0, '01-02-2012', 'LSI', 'LSI')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (6, 3, 1, '01-03-2012', NULL, 'LSI')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (7, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', 'FSA', 'FSA')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (7, 2, 0, '01-02-2012', NULL, 'FSA')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (7, 3, 1, '01-03-2012', 'RTA', 'RTA')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (8, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', 'FSA', 'FSA')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (8, 2, 0, '01-02-2012', NULL, 'FSA')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (8, 3, 1, '01-03-2012', NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (9, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', 'FSA', 'FSA')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (9, 2, 1, '01-02-2012', NULL, NULL)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (9, 3, 1, '01-03-2012', 'RTS', 'RTS')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (10, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', 'FSA','FSA')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (10, 2, 1, '01-02-2012', 'GSM','GSM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (10, 3, 1, '01-03-2012', 'RTS','RTS')  
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (11, 1, 0, '01-01-2012', 'NOP','NOP')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (11, 2, 1, '01-02-2012', 'TAP','NOP')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (11, 3, 1, '01-03-2012', 'STG','NOP')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (12, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', 'RTS','RTS')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (12, 2, 0, '01-02-2012', 'RTM','RTM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (12, 3, 1, '01-03-2012', 'LSA','RTM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (12, 4, 1, '01-03-2012', 'LSA','RTM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (12, 5, 1, '01-03-2012', 'GSM','RTM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (13, 1, 1, '01-08-2012', 'BAR','BAR')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (13, 2, 0, '01-09-2012', NULL, 'BAR')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (13, 3, 1, '01-10-2012', 'TST','TST')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (14, 1, 1, '01-08-2012', 'BAR','BAR')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (14, 2, 0, '01-09-2012', 'GIP','GIP')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (14, 3, 1, '01-10-2012', 'TST','GIP')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (15, 1, 1, '01-01-2012', 'BAR','BAR')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (15, 2, 0, '01-02-2012', 'BAR','BAR')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (15, 3, 1, '01-02-2012', 'BAR','BAR')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (15, 4, 1, '01-02-2012', 'GYM','BAR')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (16, 1, 1, '01-02-2012', 'BAR','BAR')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (16, 2, 0, '01-03-2012', NULL, 'BAR')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (16, 3, 1, '01-03-2012', 'BAR','BAR')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (16, 4, 1, '01-03-2012', 'GYM','GYM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (17, 1, 1, '01-02-2012', 'BAR', 'BAR')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (17, 2, 0, '01-03-2012', 'GIP', 'GIP')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (17, 3, 0, '01-03-2012', NULL,  'GIP') 
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (17, 4, 1, '01-03-2012', 'TST', 'GIP') 

-- -------------------------------------------
-- Following is the GID=18 test case that fails
-- -------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (18, 1, 1, '01-02-2012', 'BAR', 'BAR')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (18, 2, 0, '01-03-2012', 'BAR', 'BAR')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (18, 3, 0, '01-03-2012', NULL, 'BAR') 
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (18, 4, 1, '01-03-2012', 'TST', 'BAR') 

CHECKPOINT

INSERT INTO #Test (GID, Seq, IsLive, Eff, Name, Expected)
    SELECT  tmp.GID + (multiplier.Num * 20) AS [GID], tmp.Seq, tmp.IsLive, tmp.Eff, tmp.Name, tmp.Expected
    FROM    #Test tmp
    CROSS JOIN (
                    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [Num]
                    FROM    master.sys.objects so1
                    CROSS JOIN  master.sys.objects so2
                    CROSS JOIN  master.sys.objects so3
                ) multiplier
    WHERE   multiplier.Num <= 100000

CHECKPOINT

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Test

ALTER INDEX ALL ON #Test REBUILD

-- SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM #Test ORDER BY GID, Seq

END /* IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Test') IS NULL) */
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

DBCC FREEPROCCACHE WITH NO_INFOMSGS
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS WITH NO_INFOMSGS

PRINT '-- Original solution (Recursive CTE):'
PRINT ''

SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON

;WITH CTE AS ( 
    SELECT  T.GID, T.SEQ, T.IsLive, Expected
            , Name AS Name
            , CASE WHEN T.IsLive = 0 THEN T.SEQ ELSE NULL END As PrevNonLiveSeq
            , CASE WHEN T.IsLive = 1 THEN T.SEQ ELSE NULL END As PrevLiveSeq
            , NULL AS PerNonLiveSeqCalc
            , NULL AS PerLiveSeqCalc
            , 0 PrevSeq
            , CAST(NULL AS varchar(50)) PrevName
    FROM    #Test T
    WHERE   T.Seq = 1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT  Curr.GID, Curr.SEQ, Curr.IsLive, Curr.Expected
            ,CASE   WHEN Curr.IsLive = 0 THEN ISNULL(Curr.Name, Prev.Name) 
                    ELSE CASE   WHEN PrevNonLive.Name IS NULL THEN 
                                    CASE WHEN Prev.Name <> PrevLive.Name THEN Prev.Name ELSE Curr.Name END
                                ELSE Prev.Name END
             END

            ,CASE WHEN Curr.IsLive = 0 THEN Curr.SEQ ELSE Prev.PrevNonLiveSeq END As PrevNonLiveSeq
            ,CASE WHEN Curr.IsLive = 1 THEN Curr.SEQ ELSE Prev.PrevLiveSeq END As PrevLiveSeq
            , ISNULL(Prev.PrevNonLiveSeq, Curr.SEQ) AS PerNonLiveSeqCalc
            , ISNULL(Prev.PrevLiveSeq, Curr.SEQ) AS PerLiveSeqCalc
            , Prev.Seq PrevSeq, Prev.Name PrevName
    FROM    CTE Prev 
    JOIN    #Test Curr ON Curr.GID = Prev.GID AND Curr.SEQ = Prev.SEQ+1
    JOIN    #Test PrevNonLive ON Prev.GID = PrevNonLive.GID AND PrevNonLive.SEQ = ISNULL(Prev.PrevNonLiveSeq, Curr.SEQ)
    JOIN    #Test PrevLive ON Prev.GID = PrevLive.GID AND PrevLive.SEQ = ISNULL(Prev.PrevLiveSeq, Curr.SEQ)
) 
SELECT CTE.GID, CTE.Seq, T.IsLive
        , T.Name Input, CTE.Name [Output]
        , CASE WHEN CTE.Name = CTE.Expected OR (CTE.Name IS NULL AND CTE.Expected IS NULL) THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'FAIL' END AS Result
        , CTE.Expected
FROM CTE 
INNER JOIN #Test T on CTE.GID = T.GID AND CTE.Seq = T.Seq
ORDER BY CTE.GID, CTE.Seq

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
SET STATISTICS IO OFF

PRINT '=================================================='
------------------------------------------------------

DBCC FREEPROCCACHE WITH NO_INFOMSGS
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS WITH NO_INFOMSGS

PRINT '-- Proposed solution (OUTER APPLY):'
PRINT ''

SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON

SELECT crrnt.GID, crrnt.Seq, crrnt.IsLive,
        COALESCE(cscd.Name, crrnt.Name) AS [Output],
        CASE
            WHEN COALESCE(COALESCE(cscd.Name, crrnt.Name), '~~~') = COALESCE(crrnt.Expected, '~~~') THEN 'Pass'
            ELSE 'FAIL'
        END AS [Result],
        crrnt.Expected
FROM #Test crrnt
OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT  TOP 1 *
            FROM    #Test prir
            WHERE   prir.GID = crrnt.GID
            AND     prir.Seq < crrnt.Seq
            AND     (
                        (
                            crrnt.IsLive = 1
                        AND prir.IsLive = 0
                        AND prir.Name IS NOT NULL
                        )
                    OR  (
                            crrnt.IsLive = 0 
                        AND crrnt.Name IS NULL
                        AND (
                                (
                                    prir.IsLive = 0
                                AND prir.Name IS NOT NULL
                                )
                            OR  (
                                    prir.IsLive = 1
                                AND NOT EXISTS(
                                                SELECT  *
                                                FROM    #Test confirm
                                                WHERE   confirm.GID = prir.GID
                                                AND     confirm.Seq < prir.Seq
                                                AND     confirm.IsLive = 0
                                                AND     confirm.Name IS NOT NULL
                                            )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
            ORDER BY    prir.Seq DESC
            ) cscd

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
SET STATISTICS IO OFF
-----------------------------------
```

My execution of the above test shows:

- Original Query: CPU time = 173031 ms, elapsed time = 252708 ms, logical reads = 97,538,739
- Proposed Query = CPU time = 49125 ms,  elapsed time = 74003 ms, logical reads = 17,747,775

Hence, the original query is about 3.5 times slower for both CPU and elapsed time, and about 5 times more logical reads than my proposed query.  Be careful with Recursive CTEs ;-).

Comment: Thanks for the resonse, but I don't know if this is going to scale well when my table have over 50 years.

Comment: Ok, so how many rows are we talking about here? This should be easily testable. But with a proper index I don't see how this would be an issue, especially given the original query had many more self-JOINs plus the recursive CTE.

Comment: @KShan, I just did a quick test with just your sample data. I changed the table variable to be a temp table with a PK on GID, Seq. Original Query = 70% of estimated cost, 779 logical reads, and 102 ms. My query = 30% of estimated cost, 120 logical reads, and 155 ms. So, you should probably test on a larger data set but so far no reason for concern here regarding my query.

Comment: My concern is that I use T4's to generate the SP's and since there are over 50 columns that I need to cascade this might not be so effective. Can you tell me how I would handle additional columns in this?

Comment: @KShan, I do not see how auto-generation of the query is an issue here. The original question asks how to get a query that implements those business rules and my solution does just that. There was also no mention of auto-generation in the original question. And, I am not sure why you would be able to auto-gen the code in your current setup but not with the proposed solution; if you can do one you should be able to do the other. Lastly, check out my edit of the answer for the 6 million row performance test.